# I need to remove the first three characters of every field in an SQL column

Tags: sql

I have a table called "users" that has a column called "username." Recently, I added the prefix "El_" to every username in the database. Now I wish to delete these first three letters. How can I do that?

Comment: Please share what you have already found for us to help you with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming `MySql` you can do something like this.

`update users set username=substring(username,4);`

which will update every row to not include `el_`, but this assumes that every row starts with the El_.

sqlfiddle -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bcf6/1/0

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain why Substring 4 worked instead of 3 or 2, as in Java?

Comment: if you read the substring docs, you will see that the it is the index of where you want to want to start from.  Strings in mysql start at 1,  so 1 is E, 2 is l, 3 is _.  So you want to start from the 4th char.

Comment: in sqlite db:  remove first character :  update database_table set surah_id=substr(surah_id,2);

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 3) AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

This removes the first three characters from your result. Using RIGHT needs two arguments: the first one is the column you'd wish to display, the second one is the number of characters counting from the right of your result.

This should do!

EDIT: if you really like to remove this prefix from every username for good use an UPDATE statement as follows:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT username, id FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_numrows($result);
$i = 0;

while($i < $count){
$username = (mysql_result($result, $i, "username"));
$id = (mysql_result($result, $i, "id"));
$username = substr($username, 3);

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET username = $username WHERE id = $id);
mysqli_close($con);
i++;
}
```

Comment: This is the thorough answer. Of course there are easier (more advanced) methods, but I thought given the nature of the question it might be best if you learned how to do it the long way first...

Comment: he didn't say he was using php, and pulling this out of the db to do the work is a serious waste of resources.  Databases are very good at manipulating the data in them.

Comment: This is assuming he is using PHP and a MySQL database. Next to that, this uses a lot of seperate queries to run whilst everything could be done with just one line of SQL..

Comment: My mistake, I jumped to the thought that he would want to do it on a routine basis. I wasn't aware of that sql substring method.